# Are there any actually legitimate use for disabling right click in browsers?

Tags: javascript

A newbie friend of mine thought of attempting to "secure" the website and protect the assets through something like this. I explained why it's not going to work but it got me thinking if there are actual legitimate reasons to disable right clicking in the browsers.

Off the top of my head:
Security is obviously not one as any determined "attacker" can simply disable/override the javascript, inject their own javascript/use Chrome's Developer Tools as they control the client. At best, it'll stop non-technical users.

Attempts at protecting assets such as images obviously won't work either as they could simply save it using their browser complete with the images, use View Source and grab the assets from there, simply do a screenshot, among many other things. It'll only really stop the really non-technical and lazy users.

Preventing accidents such as say, running a transaction again by right click -> back would simply point to a deeper issue with the site code so would be a band-aid solution at best. I suppose one could make an argument that this is one use until the underlying site code is improved.

Comment: Many bank website actually block *right click* but we can open developer console using *F-12* also or by browser option. So dont think from dev tools perspective. Make server validation stronger and assume client will be hacked every time.

Comment: This is opinion-based, but the correct opinion is **no** where normal websites (vs web "apps") are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

For some more desktop-app-like pages, I've sometimes used right click for actions specific to the application.  For example, a custom context menu or modified drag/drop action.  This provides what mouse users expect in a convenient way.  (Touch users still need an alternative, however!)